Prove that $a|A|=b|B|$
This is problem $\bf 9.82$ from A Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates:

Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint finite sets of integers, and let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that if $x \in A\cup B$, then either $x + a \in A$ or $x - b \in B$.
Prove that $a\left\vert A\right\vert =
b\left\vert B\right\vert$.

I've tried constructing some examples:
$A=\{4,7\}$ and $B=\{1,3,5\}$
$A=\{2\}$ and $B=\{1\}$
I don't know where to start. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

This is, what I believe, to be the step 2 of @Keplerto's solution.
Given any finite set $X\in P(\Bbb Z)$, define $S(X)$ to be the sum of the elements of X.
Clearly, $S(X\cup Y)=S(X)+S(Y)$ for any finite disjoint sets $X,Y\in P(\Bbb Z)$.
We have
$$S(A\cup B)=S(A_0\cup B_0)$$
$$S(A)+S(B)=S(A_0)+S(B_0)=S(A-a)+S(B+b)=S(A)-a|A|+S(B)+b|B|$$
So $a|A|=b|B|$.

Yes, that was it

It would be nice if you include the proof of $A\cup B = A_0\cup B_0$ in your answer! IMO, future visitors should not have to see different posts to understand the same answer. :)

There is a typo in your answer, indeed you wrote $S(B-b)$ instead of $S(B+b)$.

Fixed. Thank you.

Let $A_0 = (A - a) \cap (A \cup B),$ $B_0 = (B+b) \cap  (A \cup B).$
Step 1. Show that $A_0 = A - a$ and $B_0 = B+b$.

Note that the hypotheses imply that $$A_0 \cup B_0 = A \cup B.$$
Because $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $|A_0| \le |A|$ and $|B_0| \le |B|$, you get $$|A| + |B| \ge |A_0| + |B_0| \ge |A_0 \cup B_0| = |A \cup B| = |A| + |B|,$$ Finiteness implies that $|A_0| = |A|$  and $|B_0| = |B|,$ and thus $A_0  = A - a$ and $B_0 = B + b.$

Step 2. This provides an alternative partition of $A \cup B$ as the disjoint union of $A_0 \cup B_0.$
Below is another hint for this step.

Another hint. You have to assign the set $A \cup B$ a certain quantity. Then calculate that quantity using the two partitions.

Could you please explain how A and B being finite imply $A_0  = A - a$ and $B_0 = B + b.$? I am having trouble at showing $x\in A - a$ implies $x\in A\cup B$.

@19021605 I've expanded that part of the answer.

@Keplerto, why do $A_0=A-a$ and $B_0=B+b$ imply $a|A|=b|B|,?$

@Angelo I will leave that to the OP, who only asked for some direction. I will post another hint if they want, but in my opinion this is the beautiful part of the problem.

@Keplerto, yes, it would be a good idea if you posted another hint.

So far I can show that the smallest element $x$ and the largest element $y$ in $A\cup B$ are in $A_0$ and $B_0$ respectively and that $A_0\cap B_0=\emptyset$. If I could show that $A_0={y-ca,...,y-2a,y-a}$ and $B_0={x+b,x+2b,...,x+db}$ for some positive integers $c$ and $d$, then I could get the following equations $y-ca=x$ and $x+db=y$, from which I could get $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{d}{c}=\frac{|B|}{|A|}$. Could I get a hint on showing $A_0={y-ca,...,y-2a,y-a}$ and $B_0={x+b,x+2b,...,x+db}$ please?

@Angelo I've posted another hint.

@19021605 Not a bad idea since that's the way simple examples look. However, for $B = {1, 7}$ and $A = {2, 8}$ that doesn't work (if I understood correctly). In fact, I don't know in general what $A_0$ and $B_0$ look like.

@Keplerto, could you tell me where you used the hypothesis that $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of $\Bbb Z$ ? It seems that they could contain non-integer numbers. Am I wrong?

@Angelo I think you are right. I have used no other properties of the elements except that they can be added / substracted. If for example you let the elements of $A$ and $B$ and the numbers $a$ and $b$ be real numbers, then you get for free that $a$ and $b$ are in rational proportion.

In fact, they can be sets of finite measure in an addition-invariant measure space, I think. For example, measurable subsets of the circle (with multiplication instead of addition).
